# Relation between the de Rham and Hodge Laplacians on the Exterior Algebra

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, laplacian

For a Kahler manifold $M$ we have two well-known Laplacians: the de Rham Laplacian $\Delta_{\text{d}} = ($d$ + $d$^\ast)^2$, and the Dolbeault Laplacian $\Delta_{\overline{\partial}} = (\overline{\partial} + \overline{\partial}^\ast)^2$. Now on smooth functions, these two operators are related by the well-known formula
$$
\Delta_{\text{d}} = 2\Delta_{\overline{\partial}}
$$
Now both these operators act on the exterior algebra. Does there exist a similar formula in this more general setting?

Comment: Yes, the identity holds for differential forms. This is what's
behind the Hodge decomposition. See your favourite book
on Kahler manifolds (Griffiths-Harris, Wells...) for an explanation.

Comment: (I don't think you want the superscript $2$ in your displayed formula.)  On a Kähler manifold, the three laplacians associated with $d$, $\partial$ and $\bar\partial$ satisfy
$$\Delta_d = 2 \Delta_{\partial} = 2 \Delta_{\bar\partial}$$
not just on functions, but also on forms.  This is why on a compact Kähler manifold, one has the decomposition of the de Rham cohomology in terms of the Dolbeault cohomology groups.  This can be found, e.g., in Well's *Differential analysis on complex manifolds*.

Comment: He does want superscripts, since what he calls Laplacian is not...
He is writing the Dirac operator instead...

Comment: Sorry, about that, superscripts in the wrong place. Yes, it still works out, but best to stick to convention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $(X,\omega)$ is Kähler, then it is always true that
$$
\Delta'=\Delta''=\frac 12\Delta,
$$
where these three Laplacians are with respect, in order, to $\partial$, $\bar\partial$ and $d$. This is valid when they act on any space of complex-valued differential forms.

More generally, you can look to differential forms with values in a hermitian vector bundle $E\to X$. In this case, take $D_E$ to be the (unique) Chern connection of $E$ and let $D_E=D'_E+D''_E$ its decomposition in the $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ part (then, by definition $D''_E=\bar\partial$).

In this case, you can again compare $\Delta'_E$ and $\Delta''_E$. They no longer coincide, but differ by a order zero operator which is expressed in terms of the curvature $\Theta(E)=D^2_E$ and the (formal) adjoint $\Lambda_\omega$ of the operator $L_\omega=\omega\wedge\bullet$ of wedge product with $\omega$. The relation is
$$
\Delta''_E=\Delta'_E+[i\Theta(E),\Lambda_\omega],
$$
where $[\bullet,\bullet]$ is the (graded) commutator.

On the other hand, coming back to complex-valued differential forms, if you merely suppose your manifold to be hermitian than the relation between the three Laplacians is a little bit more complicated. You have to introduce the torsion operator
$$
\tau=[\Lambda_\omega,\partial\omega]
$$
which is of type $(1,0)$ and order zero (observe that if $\omega$ is Kähler then $\partial\omega=0$). With these notations, you have
$$
\Delta''=\Delta'+[\partial,\tau^*]-[\bar\partial,\bar\tau^*]
$$
and
$$
\Delta=\Delta'+\Delta''-[\partial,\bar\tau^*]-[\bar\partial,\tau^*],
$$
so that $\Delta'$, $\Delta''$ and $\frac 12\Delta$ no longer coincide but they differ by linear differential operators of order $1$ only.